# How can I make diffrence between conditional statement and biconditional statement when the propositions is not clear?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, logic-translation

I cannot make difference between conditional statement and biconditional statement
I make difference between them when they are used in Natural language but I don't know which one to pick if its not clear. One example is this in first I think that was not biconditional statement but it turns on that is it.
Example: “p: If you ﬁnish your meal, then q: you can have dessert.”
in my head you can finish the meal without eating the desert, is not like "must". But the The Result says "You can have dessert if and only if you ﬁnish your meal."
But without showing the answer I would never thought that the answer was p ↔ q.

Comment: “If you ﬁnish your meal, then you have dessert.” doesn't look like a biconditional to me. Having dessert is a necessary condition for finishing meal, not a sufficient condition. However when your mom says that to you at a dinner table she clearly "means" it as a biconditional..

Comment: That's where I get confused too. Is not specifically said because for the both you can use if then so if its not clear I don't know which one to go for.

Comment: Only coloquially (not mathematically) does "If you finish your meal then you can have desert" imply "If you don't finish your meal then you can't have desert.  But mathematically, I'd say if that was the author's intention s/he definitely needed to say so and since s/he didn't, I'd say it is *not* a biconditional.

Comment: I'd interpret q: you can have dessert as the statement being about the offer to have dessert.  Not the actual eating of desert.  I'd see this as if you finish your meal then it will be true that you are offered dessert (and no-one cares whether you eat it or not).  So I'd view this as conditional:  If $p\to q$: If you finish meal you will be offered desert.  And if you don't finish the meal, you may or may not be offered desert; we don't know.

Answer (score 4):

This is an English question, not a math one.  In English, if ... then often means if and only if.  In math it is clear that an implication is true if the antecedent is false.  You have to look at the context.  In this case, there is a clear English implication that if you don't finish your meal you cannot have dessert, which makes it biconditional.  The "you can have dessert" is permissive, so having dessert is not required even if the meal is finished.

Answer (score 0):

> Example: “p: If you ﬁnish your meal, then q: you can have dessert.” in my head you can finish the meal without eating the desert, is not like "must".

A simple test: Negate both the antecedent and consequent. If the statement is still true, then you have a biconditional relationship.

Applying this test to your example: Is it true that, if you **DO NOT** finish your meal, then you **CANNOT** have dessert? If so, you have a biconditional relationship.

The principle is the same whether it is stated in natural language or symbolic logic.

$$(P \implies Q) \land (\neg P \implies \neg Q) \space \space \equiv \space \space P \iff Q$$